# 1NF to 3NF -- Review

Tags: database, normalization

So I started out with this problem in my textbook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTrTw.jpg
and then I had to find all of the dependencies and create a 3NF from the original... I have spent hours trying to figure this out and get it correct. Can someone please provide feedback on my so far final product?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzeP7.jpg (I know this is in the relational model and not ERD -- I figured that this would be easier)

Comment: Please list your functional dependencies.

Comment: No functional dependencies were given, I found partial and transitional dependnecies to go from 1NF to 3NF

Comment: Attributes are functional dependencies (FDs), partial dependencies are FDs and transitive dependencies are a composition of FDs. The point of listing the FDs you identified is so that I can check whether you used them correctly to normalize. I can derive FDs from your solution but then I'm comparing your answer against itself and my own interpretation of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with most of your solution. However, a few details stand out:

- You introduced either `TRAINING_ID` or `TRAINING_DESCR` in `Training`. The original `EMP_TRAINING` had single domain of values. Normalization would only give you the bridge table.
- You introduced either `EDUC_CODE` or `EDUC_DESCR` in `Education`. The original `EMP_EDUCATION` had a single domain of values. Normalization would only give you the bridge table.
- You introduced `EMP_CODE` as an attribute of `JOB_CLASS`. I see no matching attribute in the original.
- `DEPEN_NUM` isn't wrong, but it depends on whether you interpret `EMP_DEPENDENTS` as an ordered or unordered list. I would've used `(EMP_NUM, DEPEN_FNAME)` as key for `Dependents`. Yours is an equally valid solution.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am confused about your first three points. For the first two, training and education is a many to many relationship because an employee can have many trainings or degrees and a degree or training can belong to many employees so I would need to break it down with a bridge yes?  And for the third it should be EMP_Num which would fix that I believe

Comment: Following the rules of normalization would've given you a relation `(EMP_NUM, EMP_EDUCATION)`. There is no separate code and description in the original data. The same for training.

Comment: `JOB_CLASS -> EMP_NUM` in `Job` is wrong - there are two employees with job class SLS. You already have `EMP_NUM -> JOB_CLASS` in `Employee` which captures the right dependency.

Comment: So I would take out the training and education tables completely, leave the two bridges just like they are and remove the EMP_NUM from Job table?

Comment: What if I made Job_class and emp_num both primary keys of the job table? - would that fix the issue?

Comment: I noticed that the two employees with job class SLS have different base salaries and commission rates, so `JOB_CLASS` doesn't determine `EMP_BASE_SALARY` or `EMP_COMMISSION RATE`. I would move those two attributes to `Employee` and scrap the `Job` table.

Comment: reaanb - I took your advice and changed things around with what you have said so far -- does everything look right now aside from the Training and Education tables? I am still confused as I thought you needed bridges whenever there was a M:N relationship.

http://imgur.com/XnOTPji

Comment: Note your column names - better to use the original `EMP_BASE_SALARY` and `EMP_COMMISSION_RATE`. You're correct that M:N relationships require a separate table, just like multivalued attributes. In this case the original data had no attributes that depended on `EMP_EDUCATION` and `EMP_TRAINING` so there's no indication that those refer to entities.

Comment: Keep in mind that this discussion of entities, attributes and relationships is conceptual. Normalization operates on the logical level and don't care about ER semantics, it just works with domains, relations, keys and dependencies.

Comment: So the training and education table can be completely taken away, And the bridge tables stay as they are?

Comment: Yes, except I would recommend using the original column names.

Comment: So this is what I have now... http://imgur.com/cKsVBMd

But, with this, it is saying that an Employee can have many trainings and educations but a training or education can only belong to one employee which isn't true. OR is that saying that it can only belong to one employee with a unique EMP_ID since the TRAINING and EDUCATION table both have composite keys?

Comment: Education's composite key says that the combination of EMP_NUM and EDU_CODE is unique and maps to a single employee, which is obvious because the employee's number is part of the combination. However, the same EDU_CODE can appear multiple times in the table, for different employees. Same argument for training.

Comment: Ah that makes sense!! So everything looks correct now?

Comment: I would rename TRAINING_ID to EMP_TRAINING and EDU_CODE to EMP_EDUCATION. Sorry to harp on about column names, but normalization is a very deterministic process. Renaming variables in an algebraic solution isn't good form except in rare cases, the same applies here.

Comment: No, no I thank you for that! I am trying to learn the best way so thank you very much! Now one final question hopefully - let's say that EMP_BASE_SALARY was based on both EMP_TRAINING and EMP_EDUCATION. How would I change everything to show that?

Comment: If `EMP_TRAINING` and `EMP_EDUCATION` were single-valued attributes, it would be easy. The functional dependency `(EMP_TRAINING, EMP_EDUCATION) -> EMP_BASE_SALARY` would translate into a table `(EMP_TRAINING PK, EMP_EDUCATION PK, EMP_BASE_SALARY)`. However, we allow employees to have multiple values for each. One way might be to assign a base salary to each training or education value and choose the highest option for an employee. There are many other possible ways, the model would depend on how we want to do it.

Comment: so if I added SALARY_ADDITION to both TRAINING and EDUCATION tables like so (http://imgur.com/6SKFX6y) -- would that help? And then create a new table Salary with EMP_NUM as the primary key and EMP_BASE_SALARY, SALARY_ADDITION as foreign keys?

It looks like the more education and training they have (together) the higher their salary is

Comment: Is the SALARY_ADDITION employee-specific or just dependent on the education/training? If the latter, it should go in separate tables else you have a partial dependency. There's no need to create a new table with EMP_NUM as PK, you can just add the attribute to the Employee table.

Comment: The salary addition would be dependent on the amount of training and the amount of education.  So I would just create Salary table with SALARY_ID as primary key and what else?

Comment: How do you determine that amount? Highest level or number of entries? How would a Ph.D. with L1 training compare to a BBA with L15 training? For highest level, I would record `(EMP_EDUCATION PK, ORDERING, SALARY_ADDITION)` and `(EMP_TRAINING, ORDERING, SALARY_ADDITION)` then select the highest value by ordering. If you're sure higher qualifications can't ever earn less, you can do away with the `ORDERING` field and select the highest `SALARY_ADDITION` for an employee.

Comment: eh I am not sure, I am just going to say that salary is not based upon any attributes listed. so all of this is now correct though? http://imgur.com/AcCqcqh

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for all of your help!

Comment: No problem. Please review the normalization steps to ensure you understand how to get to the solution. Also, please mark my answer as accepted if you can.